# Why does my string not display with the decimal points I want?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a program where if I input the degree, it converts it into radian and then calculate its Sine, Cosine and Tangent using Taylor's Theory.
Note that I am not supposed to invoke the math module.

```
def sinAns(rad):
    rad=rad
    radPlaceHolder=rad
    counter=0
    numberForFacto=1
    tOld=rad
    tNew=0
    tPlaceHolder=rad
    pr=precision+1
    tDiff=1
    sinAns=0

    while abs(tDiff)>.5*10**(-pr):       
        tOld=tPlaceHolder
        tNew=(-1*tOld*rad*rad)/((numberForFacto+1)*(numberForFacto+2))
        tPlaceHolder=tNew       
        counter+=1
        numberForFacto+=2
        tDiff=abs(tOld)-abs(tNew)
        radPlaceHolder+=tNew
        sinAns=radPlaceHolder
    return sinAns
```

This is how my code for calculating Sine looks like.

```
print("{0:}{1:{2}f}".format("sin= ", sinAns(rad), precision))
```

This is the line where it prints the value later in the program, and I already have the precision defaulted at 10. But when I run the program, it displays 0.500000 instead of the precision I want it to be. Even if I change the precision to any other value between 2-10, it ALWAYS shows 0.500000.

Any idea how to fix this? Have been tweaking around for an hour and still haven't got a clue.

Comment: You need the `.` to tell it you mean precision *after* the decimal point, e.g. `.10f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the point `.`:

```
print("{0}{1:.{2}f}".format("sin= ", sinAns(rad), precision))
           # ^
```

Comment: Oh god I am actually dumb. Thanks for the answer by the way.